# SQL Unit Testing with TSQLUNIT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unit-testing, tsqlunit

I noticed something weird while unit testing an update/insert stored procedure using TSQLUNIT on SQL Server 2012. when I call **Exec tsu_RunTests**, my test procedure runs but with unexpected behaviour. the line in the code that calls my original stored procedure is executed but no actual updates or inserts made to the database table as expected. Is there a valid reason for this behaviour? Or is this a bug I need to pay much attention to? I notice that when I execute the same original stored procedure outside of the test procedure, it works fine.

Comment: How do you check whether data is inserted / updated? Perhaps tsqlunit is performing an automatic rollback after running the tests?

Comment: This is what I am not sure of. So far, I have not seen from the documentation that it does this but wanted to ask if anyone else is aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Default parameter for each stored procedure and set this `@IsTest` parameter to true when use these stored procedures in tsu_RunTests.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE orginal_proc
    --@parameter_name 
    @IsTest BIT = 0
AS
    if @IsTest <> 1 Begin
    --  Test statements
    End Else Begin
    --  statements
    End 
GO
```

you also can use `@@NESTLEVEL` for check that your procedure execute directly or execute by other procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE orginal_proc
    --@parameter_name 
AS

    if @@NESTLEVEL <> 1 Begin
    --  Test statements
    End Else Begin
    --  statements
    End
GO
```

**EDIT :** Stored Procedure Code must be like below :

```
If @@NESTLEVEL <> 1 Print 'Befor Update Message'
If @@NESTLEVEL = 1 Begin
   Update YourTable
   Set ...
End
If @@NESTLEVEL <> 1 Print 'After Update Message'
```

Comment: Nice idea you have there. What I have instead are print statements in my Original procedure to print a statement before the UPDATE statement and after, and both Print statements are run as the messages show up in message. Just that the actual update does not take place and I wanted to verify that this is what is expected and not some issue.